# FactoryGirl belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, factory-bot

I have a factory where I define a location in `factories/locations.rb`. I'm using Mongoid and Rails 3.1.1 with ruby 1.9.3.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :location do
      name Faker::Name.name
      description "Down by the river"
    end
end
```

And then I want to define a fitness camp which belongs_to a location (and therefore has a location_id attribute).

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :fitness_camp do
    title "Parkour"
    association :location_id, :factory => :location
  end
end
```

This *works* but, is the result of my hacking, not what I read in the docs. From the getting started guide ( https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) it seems this should be as simple as:

```
  factory :fitness_camp do
    title "Parkour"
    location
  end
```

Am I missing something? Does this indicate my models might not be configured correctly?

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: look here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/9713995255/factorygirl-2-1-0-brings-the-heat

Comment: I looked there -- still unclear. I'll look through the source code later today.

Comment: What version of FactoryGirl are you using?

Comment: factory_girl-2.2.0, but that is not my problem -- answer below

Comment: You can accept your own answer, which is good practice to indicate that you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was an idiot -- I had `validates_numericality_of :location_id`

```
class FitnessCamp

  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, :type => String

  belongs_to :location

  validates_presence_of  :location_id, :title
  validates_numericality_of :location_id
```

Mad props to Radar (Ryan Bigg) for helping me through this.